# Playing sounds sequentially on android's google chrome (given the new restrictions on playing sound)

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, audio

I have a small app that plays sequential sounds (a teaching app playing the sillables of a word)

This could be accomplished by firing an event right after each sound stopped playing. Something like:

```
var sounds = new Array(new Audio("1.mp3"), new Audio("2.mp3"));
var i = -1;
playSnd();

function playSnd() {
   i++;
   if (i == sounds.length) return;
   sounds[i].addEventListener('ended', playSnd);
   sounds[i].play();
}
```

[(source)](https://pro9ram.wordpress.com/2013/02/21/playing-html-5-audio-sequentially-via-javascript/)

However, now android chrome has implemented some new restrictions on how to play sound: Sound events must all be fired by a user action.

So, when I run code very similar to the above, the first sound plays, and then I get

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() can only be initiated by a user gesture.
```

How can a sequence of sounds, determined at run time, be played on Android's Chrome?

Comment: My Google Chrome version is 62.0.3202.94... I used your code and it works perfectly for me...

Comment: can you share the browser version and other details? Note: recently google announced that it is going to block autoplay videos. check https://www.theverge.com/2017/9/15/16311310/google-chrome-autoplay-videos-january

Answer (score 2):

To start with, **Google Chrome on Android** has been having the limitation of not allowing applications to play **HTML audio(s)** without an *explicit action* by the user. However, it is different than how stock browser(s), in most cases, handles it.

> The reason, as **Chromium Org** puts it, is that, *Autoplay is not honored on android as it will cost data usage*.
>
> You may find more details on the same [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=138132).
>
> Apart from the fact that this results in *wastage of bandwidth*, this also makes some sense, since mobile devices are used in public and in houses, where *unsolicited sound* from random Web sites could be a **nuisance**.

However, in the later versions, this idea was over ruled and *Chrome on Android* started allowing autoplay of *HTML audios* and *videos* on it. Again after a set of reviews and discussions, this feature was **reverted** to what it was, making it *mandatory for a user action to invoke HTML audios and videos on the Chrome for Android*.

> [Here](https://codereview.chromium.org/428263004/) is something that I found more on the same. As it says, the reason stated was that *"We're going to gather some data about how users react to autoplaying videos in order to decide whether to keep this restriction"*. And hence the playing option without a user action was reverted back.
>
> You can also find more about the blocking of _autoplay of audio(s) and video(s) here on [Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/leemathews/2017/09/15/google-chrome-stop-autoplay/#8831d6c78efa) and [The Verge](https://www.theverge.com/2017/9/15/16311310/google-chrome-autoplay-videos-january).

However, this is something that I can suggest you to try which will help you achieve what you intend to. All you have to do is *copy this code* and paste in your *Chrome for Android*. This helps you reset the flag which is default set to **not allowing to play HTML audios and videos without user interaction**:

> `chrome://flags/#disable-gesture-requirement-for-media-playback`
>
> OR
>
> `about:flags/#disable-gesture-requirement-for-media-playback`

If the above procedure doesn't help/work for you, you can do this:

> Go into `chrome://flags` OR `about:flags` (this will direct you to `chrome://flags`) and **Enable** the "Disable gesture requirement for media playback" option (which is actually the same as the above URL specified).

Comment: Setting flags  seems to be a way  to solve it for a particular user, but it seems that a web designer cannot set the flag for their users, right?

Comment: No he cannot. This action is to be done manually by every user on his/her phone. The reason being what I listed out already : 1. To avoid the wastage of bandwidth. 2. To avoid unsolicited/unintended sound being played from random websites.